# sequences: finding a formula for a function 4, 1, 2, 1, 4

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to find and prove an arithmatic formula for a function. my teacher gave us a list of properties that the function meets. by using substitution on the properties given, i was able to find a pattern. it looks like the pattern creates almost like a triangular shape 4, 1, 2, 1, 4 . its super strange cause the pattern decreases then increases. also, a number like (4,1) produces the same result as (4,3). can anyone help me figure out what the pattern is to this sequence, so i can keep working on the next step? (the next step is actually proving the formula-- which i plan to do with some sort of induction). i feel like ive tried everything!

F(0,0)=0

f(0,1)=1 
f(1,0)=1
f(1,1)=1

f(0,2)=2
f(2,1)=1
f(1,2)=1 
f(2,2)=2

f(3,0)=3 
f(3,1)=1 
f(1,3)=1
f(3,2)=1 
f(2,3)=1 
f(3,3)=3

f(4,0)=4
f(4,1)=1 
f(1,4)=1
f(4,2)=2 
f(2,4)=2
f(4,3)=1 
f(3,4)=1
f(4,4)=4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(0,0)=0, f(m,n)=\operatorname{gcd}(m,n)$ if at least one of $m,n$ is non-zero fits all the data presented.  Of course, there are many other functions that do, as well, but this is pretty accessible.

Comment: thank you! it seems so obvious now!

Comment: @tara If this answer helped you, you should click the check box to accept it :).